# How to sort maximum occurrence of a value in array with respect to cumulative column,current column and distance

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have an array of indices of distances ordered.

```
d    
array([[  0.        ,   5.38516481,   8.60232527,   7.61577311,
          3.        ,   4.12310563,  12.36931688],
       [  5.38516481,   0.        ,   5.        ,   7.        ,
          7.07106781,   2.        ,  13.34166406],
       [  8.60232527,   5.        ,   0.        ,   6.164414  ,
          8.77496439,   6.70820393,  10.34408043],
       [  7.61577311,   7.        ,   6.164414  ,   0.        ,
          8.18535277,   8.06225775,  10.04987562],
       [  3.        ,   7.07106781,   8.77496439,   8.18535277,
          0.        ,   6.164414  ,  10.09950494],
       [  4.12310563,   2.        ,   6.70820393,   8.06225775,
          6.164414  ,   0.        ,  13.92838828],
       [ 12.36931688,  13.34166406,  10.34408043,  10.04987562,
         10.09950494,  13.92838828,   0.        ]])
a = np.argsort(d,axis=1)[:,-3:]
a

array([[3, 2, 6],
       [3, 4, 6],
       [0, 4, 6],
       [5, 4, 6],
       [3, 2, 6],
       [2, 3, 6],
       [0, 1, 5]], dtype=int64)
```

Need check from last column to first column cumulatively.

I tried to do :

```
unique, counts = numpy.unique(a, return_counts=True)
x = dict(zip(unique, counts))
sorted(x.items(), key = lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)

[(6, 6), (3, 4), (2, 3), (4, 3), (0, 2), (5, 2), (1, 1)]
```

In the above list of tuples both `(2, 3) and (4, 3)` have same counts. But when we check cumulatively from last column to first column. I need to get the list as `(4, 3), (2, 3)`, Since because 4 occurred before 2 in the columns.

**Expected output of 3 maximum occurance:**

```
[6, 3, 4]
```

**for validation check this:**

```
a = np.array([[2, 3, 6],
   [2, 4, 5],
   [0, 4, 3],
   [1, 4, 6],
   [2, 3, 5],
   [3, 2, 6],
   [0, 1, 5]])
unique, counts = numpy.unique(a, return_counts=True)
x = dict(zip(unique, counts))
sorted(x.items(), key = lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)

[(2, 4), (3, 4), (4, 3), (5, 3), (6, 3), (0, 2), (1, 2)]
```

In the above list we need to get the list as `(3, 4) then (2, 4)` and either of `(5, 3), (6, 3) and then (4, 3)` since `(5, 3), (6, 3)` occurred in the last column first before 4. In the end if there is same count in same column like the pair `(5, 3), (6, 3)`, make the the index first appear which has maximum distance as shown in `d` array above.

**Note :** Validation matrix is created manually and distances are not present, where as the first matrices are real.

Please give me solution which is general and can apply to any such arrays.

I tried to code but not able to get the proper logic to do the task. I know I apply `np.argmax()` along columns but I need to check cumulatively.

If you didn't understand any part of the question, please comment I will clarify.

Comment: Dictionaries are inherently unsorted, so they won't mainatain any sequential information.  If you don't need a dictionary, you could just stack `unique` and `counts` and sort by `counts` and end up with an array with the information you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following requires numpy 1.13+ because it uses the new `axis` parameter to `unique`.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[2, 3, 6],
   [2, 4, 5],
   [0, 4, 3],
   [1, 4, 6],
   [2, 3, 5],
   [3, 2, 6],
   [0, 1, 5]]) * 1000 # do not rely on uniques being 0,1,2,3...

# add column indices
ac = np.c_[a.ravel(), np.outer(np.ones((len(a),), a.dtype), np.arange(3)).ravel()]

# find uniq pairs (data, col ind)
uniq, cnts = np.unique(ac, return_counts=True, axis=0)
uniquniq, uniqidx = np.unique(uniq[:, 0], return_inverse=True)

# make grid uniq els x col idx fill with counts
fullcnts = np.zeros((len(uniquniq), 3), dtype=int)
fullcnts[uniqidx, uniq[:, 1]] = cnts
cumcnts = np.cumsum(fullcnts[:, ::-1], axis=-1)

# order by sum and then column cnts as tie breakers
order = np.lexsort((cumcnts[:, 1], cumcnts[:, 0], cumcnts[:, 2]))[::-1]
result = list(zip(uniquniq[order], cumcnts[order, 2]))

# [(3000, 4), (2000, 4), (6000, 3), (5000, 3), (4000, 3), (1000, 2), (0, 2)]
```

Line-by-line:

1) we make a new array that looks like [(2, 0), (3, 1), (6, 2), (2, 0), (4, 1), (5, 2), ..., i.e. each element of a and its column index.

2) That way we can make `unique` count occurrences by column. For example the count returned for uniq element (2, 0) will be the number of 2's in the zeroth column.

3) from the unique pairs we now extract the actual unique values. `uniqidx` is the same as `uniq` but with each element replaced with its position (index) in `uniquniq`

4) next we build a table uniques x columns

5) and place all the counts at their appropriate positions

6) the counts we then sum. (actually it is not necessary to use the cumulative sum, but it does no harm either)

7) we now have all the pieces needed to rank the uniques. `lexsort` is an indirect sort like `argsort`, only you can sort by multiple vectors, the last vector passed is considered first. We put `cumcnts[:, 2]` there which are the total counts, next (in case of a tie) `cumcnts[:, 0]` which are the counts for the last column and finally, `cumcnts[:, 1]` which are the counts for last and middle column combined. As mentioned in (6) we could also have used the count of the middle column alone here.

8) `lexsort` returns an index (`order`) which we use to arrange the uniques and their counts in the right order.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain it a bit more specific about each line of code. The solution was great and glad to know that numpy has many features. @PaulPanzer

Comment: Thank You so much! for your time. I am new to programming, So need to learn a lot. Stack overflow community members are excellent. @PaulPanzer